# R java interface R_HOME is not set

Tags: r, jri

I'm I'm struggling with JRI installation on mac with no success. 
I got an R 3.1 working version, and a JDK working version 1.7.0_67. 
I installe RJava trougth the command install.packages("rJava") successfully, but when I try to run the examples from Netbrans I got the error:

R_HOME is not set. Please set all required environment variables before running this program.
Unable to start R

I setted the R_HOME variable in the bash_profile file as follows: 
export R_HOME=export R_HOME=$(which R)

and if I type R_HOME appears:

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R (as I suppose should be).

But still I got the same error. 
I tried with R 2.15 too butI still got the same error.

Any suggestion?????

Thanks in advances,

Rossella

Comment: Try to set R_HOME to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources, if i recall r home should be set to where the bin directory is

Comment: Tkans for your suggestion, I tried but unfortunetelly still don't work. If I print the $R_HOME it's give me: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources as I expected, and also if in R I use the command R.home() I got
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources". Any suggestions? Thanks in advances Rossella

Comment: Did you set up Path and Java_Home? if so please type them in the command line and show it, also can you send a snapshot of your project structure in net beans?